# Can I have more than 8 active skills?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

As I get more skill points, I've noticed I have more than 8 active skills.  Can I actually use more than 8 in combat, or do I need to respec and get a little more focused with my skill point distribution?

Comment: I haven't had to look at this yet in DA:I with my current character, but in past games, I seem to recall being able to access unmapped skills from the quick toggle menu (where you take potions/use grenades and such). There was just a submenu you could access from there with all your skills. Haven't looked closely at that menu in inquisition since I haven't needed it (and I'm at work right now), but pretty sure that was the case for past dragon age games, have you looked there maybe?

Comment: @gnomed I don't see any sort of quick toggle menu this time around.  On the right side of the pause button it shows you what potions you have equipped, but no amount of clicking gets it to bring up a second menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can only use 8 active skills at a time. You could keep a couple of extras, and swap them around between battles, but I would not recommend it.

As you say, I'd recommend a respec and focus your skills a little more. I often found that going for 1 tree mainly, along with a secondary and the specialization worked the best. For example, my mage is a Fire/Spirit Knight Enchanter, with points mostly focused in Fire.

Focusing on certain skills like this will make the individual skills much more powerful.

*On a side note: if your companions have more than 8 skills, they will actually use them if the AI is controlling them, provided the skills are enabled through the tactics window.*

Comment: When using keyboard/mouse controls, the action bar is limited to 8 skills, same as a gamepad.

Comment: I hate it when the answer is no, but such is gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Limited to 8 for pc. But when you giving AI tactics for other party members, you can make them use automatically which is not included in their skills bar, keep that in mind.